# Powershell Script running, but no action taken

Tags: powershell, file-copying

The following 2-line script attempts to copy a file from a source folder to a destination folder (where a copy of the file already exist).

```bsh
Copy-Item -Path "D:\Thunderbird\Profiles\xyz.default\ImapMail\imap.gmail.com\msgFilterRules.dat" -Destination D:\Dropbox\Bkup\Bkp_Thunderbird\ -Force
Write-Host "Script executed"
```

The script executes without error (!) - i.e., I see "Script executed" in PowerShell - but **no files are copied**.

I have:

- validated that `Source` and `Destination` paths are correct.
- tried the script with and without quotes in the source path.
- tried it with Thunderbird both open and not.
- tried it with and without a `"\"` at the end of `-Destination`.
- tried it with and without `-Force` at the end of the line.

Comment: How did you determine that the file wasn't actually being copied?

Comment: Do you get the correct output (i.e. destination file object with the same attributes as the source file) if you pass `-PassThru`?

Comment: Thank you both. I knew the file wasn't copied by the date-stamp.
It seem the "-Force" switch was NOT doing anything! I'm able to get around this by first checking for and deleting files in the destination folder. I don't understand why "-Force" fails to enable file override, however.

Comment: I took BACON's suggestion. Apparently the file IS being overridden, but Windows Explorer wasn't updating - even after F5 (many people have this issue: see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-date-modified-is-not-updating/c4b4e4e7-2233-490e-929f-46c98fffd00b.

Comment: Thank you both again for your help